# How to know the sdcard has enough free size to write in on Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I've got the "No space left on device" IOException when writing file.
I wish to avoid it happens before writing.
How should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Hum can't you simply handle the exception: try to write, if it works fine, if it doesn't it triggers your exception and you know there is not enough memory. Unless your trying to do something more complex that should be enough

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just want to know if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ecede996463a4058

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getBlockCount();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
```

Comment: Thank you! May be you could fix the layout.